# URL field only for certain reference types with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, urls

I'm using `biblatex` for my references. My `bib` file includes many references which I have imported from different sources. Not all references have a `url` entry and some of them are bogus. I now like to suppress the `url` entries by default but use them for specific reference types, e.g. `@manual`, only.

Currently I use:

```
\usepackage[
    style=numeric-comp,
    sorting=none,
    doi=false,
    isbn=false,
    url=true,
    eprint=false,
    maxnames=99
]{biblatex}
```

Is there a possibility to say `url=false` in general but something like `manual={url=true}`? I like to avoid going to my big `bib` file and comment out all other `url` entries.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifentrytype{manual}{%
  }{%
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urldate}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@manual{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just came across this answer because of [Biblatex: Surpessing urldate does not work (\clearfield)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278890/35864) and it seems that with the current version `\clearfield{urldate}` doesn't work any more, now `\clearfield{urlyear}` is needed.

Answer (score 19):

I want to provide an other solution. You can work with the command `\DeclareFieldFormat`. In this way you can simple add new entry types or you are able to set special formation for different entry types.

The command `\DeclareFieldFormat` has a star version which sets the defined for every entry type. In the next step you can define a special setting for one or more entry types by using the optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{url}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[manual]{url}{\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{urldate}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[manual]{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@manual{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
  urldate={2012-04-19}
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
  urldate={2012-04-19}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

@lockstep: I hope it's ok that I take your example.

[image]

Comment: +1. The benefit of your method is that it avoids complicated nested conditionals if one wants to allow URL's for several types; the drawback is that one has to look up and copy the original format definitions of `url` and `urldate`.

Comment: @lockstep: In my opinion the file `biblatex.def` is part of the documentation. However the questioner is Martin ;-) I think is able to read the file ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I don't think having to look at `biblatex.def` is a big deal, either. However some contributed styles aren't very good at managing unit punctuation. So suppressing fields with the `\clearfield`-type commands is generally better at avoiding spurious punctuation than an empty formatting directive.

Comment: @Audrey: DO you think we should support every contributed style. I think in this way it's a bug of the package ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Supporting every contributed style and offering a solution robust to bugs (which are inevitably something a user must face sometimes) are two very different things.

Comment: @Audrey: Indeed.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative approach, if you are using biber, is to do this before biblatex sees any data at all. Put this in your biber.conf:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" map_overwrite="1">
      <map>
        <per_type>MANUAL</per_type>
        <map_step map_field_set="URL" map_field_target="URL"/>
      </map>
      <map>
        <map_step map_field_set="URL" map_null="1"/>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
```

You could also just use one `map` clause and list all the entry types you want to remove urls from, each in their own `per_entrytype` line.

Comment: +1 This reminded me to edit another biber solution I posted. `urldate` should be suppressed, too. I guess just with `<map_step map_field_set="URLDATE" map_null="1"/>` in the second `map` clause.

Comment: Yes, you can have as many `map_step` items as you like and they are processed in order, seeing the results of the previous steps. The `<map>` sections are mainly for grouping so that you can apply some transformations only to specific entrytypes or datasources etc.

Answer (score 4):

For `@online` entries, `biblatex` prints the URL and date even if configured with `url=false`.

(example code was modified from @lockstep's answer)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[url=false]{biblatex}


\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
  urldate = {2014-03-06}
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: This is highly dependant on the style you are using. For example, all biblatex-chem styles do not print `url`.

Answer (score 3):

Building on @PLK's answer, here is an example `biber.conf` that selectively removes URLs from specified entry types, rather than selectively keeps them.

Note that entry types aren't case sensitive.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" map_overwrite="1">
      <map>
        <!-- Hide urls in listed types -->
        <per_type>InProceedings</per_type>
        <per_type>Book</per_type>
        <per_type>Conference</per_type>
        <per_type>InCollection</per_type>
        <per_type>Article</per_type>
        <map_step map_field_set="URL" map_null="1"/>
        <map_step map_field_set="UrlDate" map_null="1"/>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
```