# Temporarily override biblatex reference options

Tags: biblatex, urls, chicago-style

I am using `biblatex-chicago` with the option `url=false`, but I want to include a URL for just a few references. Is there a command that would allow me to reintroduce the URL for just these references while maintaining the universal option?

Comment: Is the situation where you want to remove the URL limited to certain entry types (and if yes, which) or is it random? If it's only for certain types, the situation may be much easier.

Comment: It is for a book that is available online. Obviously, using different entry types would work, but I am using citeulike, which does not allow the full-range of bibtex entry types. I am using chromeos, so have no access to JabRef. Hence I just wanted to be able to have a single book entry that includes a url.

Comment: It's not really good style and a bit of abusing of ``bibtex``'s fields, but you could just put the URL into the ``note`` field if you have it available on citeulike.

Comment: The question is, do you want to include the URL for all books, if there is one, and no other entrytypes?

Comment: I have since switched to bibsonomy and just resigned myself to the fact that I will have to manually delete urls from papers and books, since doi is preferable anyway. This way, I just add the url to entries that I want to have it in the citation. Not really a proper solution.

Comment: @DavidRowthorn Why not just use the `@online` entry type? URL-related fields are always printed for this entry type, regardless of the `url` option setting.

Comment: If you can specify what the conditions are for having URL appear (what entrytypes etc.) this can easily be done with biber's sourcemapping feature.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using sharelatex.com which does not yet support biber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow URLs for indiviual references, add an `options = {url=true},` field to the respective `.bib` entries. (For enabling URLs for certain entry types see [URL field only for certain reference types with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52601/url-field-only-for-certain-reference-types-with-biblatex))

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[url=false,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}  

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  url = {www.alpha.com},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  url = {www.bravo.com},
  options = {url=true},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]