# Biblatex - How can I suppress some fields for multiple entry types?

Tags: biblatex

Based on lockstep's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52601/url-field-only-for-certain-reference-types-with-biblatex?rq=1), I wrote

```
\ifentrytype{book,collection,incollection}{%
}{%
\clearfield{url}%
\clearfield{urldate}%
\clearfield{review}%
\clearfield{series}%
}%
```

to suppress the URL and its date for the listed source types. The catch is, it even suppresses the URL for @ONLINE sources now, even if I only specify one entry type. Is the code above outdated or is it due to my settings?

### Output

[image]

### MWE, made after musicman's answer

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
style=authoryear-icomp
]{biblatex}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
\ifentrytype{book,collection,incollection}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urldate}%
    \clearfield{review}%
    \clearfield{series}%%
}{}
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test-lit.bib}
@book{Abook,
  author = {AAAAbook, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
}
@online{Bonline,
  author = {BBBBonline, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
}
@collection{Ccollection,
    editor = {CCCCColletionEditor, C.},
    year = {2002},
    title = {Charlie},
    url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
}
@incollection{Dincollection,
    author = {DDDDincollection, D.},
    year = {2002},
    crossref = {Ccollection},
    title = {Delta},
    url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test-lit.bib}

\nocite{*}

\listfiles

\begin{document}

Abc.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: look at the synthax: `if {} else {your commands}` - it's applicated only on entrytypes which are **not** `book,collection,incollection`, so @online of course, too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently the rules have to be defined on an per-type-basis so the answer is: not possible.

### Output

[image]

### MWE

```
    \documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
style=authoryear-icomp
]{biblatex}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
\ifentrytype{book}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urldate}%
    \clearfield{review}%
    \clearfield{series}%%
}{}
\ifentrytype{collection}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urldate}%
    \clearfield{review}%
    \clearfield{series}%%
}{}
\ifentrytype{incollection}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urldate}%
    \clearfield{review}%
    \clearfield{series}%%
}{}
}

%%%%not working:
%%%\AtEveryBibitem{%
%%%\ifentrytype{book,collection,incollection}{%supresses the fields for those entrytypes
%%% \clearfield{url}%
%%% \clearfield{urldate}%
%%% \clearfield{review}%
%%% \clearfield{series}%
%%%}{}%the other entrytypes are nore affected
%%%}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test-lit.bib}
@book{Abook,
  author = {AAAAbook, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
}
@online{Bonline,
  author = {BBBBonline, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
}
@collection{Ccollection,
    editor = {CCCCColletionEditor, C.},
    year = {2002},
    title = {Charlie},
    url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
}
@incollection{Dincollection,
    author = {DDDDincollection, D.},
    year = {2002},
    crossref = {Ccollection},
    title = {Delta},
    url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test-lit.bib}

\nocite{*}

\listfiles

\begin{document}

Abc.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: you are right. shorter way using the already included `ifthen`-package: `\AtEveryBibitem{\ifthenelse{\ifentrytype{book}\OR\ifentrytype{collection}\OR\ifentrytype{incollection}}{
    \clearfield{url}\clearfield{urldate}\clearfield{review}\clearfield{series}}{}}`

Comment: I just came across this answer because of [Biblatex: Surpessing urldate does not work (\clearfield)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278890/35864) and it seems that with the current version `\clearfield{urldate}` doesn't work any more, now `\clearfield{urlyear}` is needed.

Comment: To suppress the issue from the ``\cite`` in apa author-year style, to ensure you get ``Author (date)`` and not ``Author (date, issue)``, this does it: ``\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{issue}}``.

Answer (score 2):

```
\ifentrytype{book,collection,incollection}{%supresses the fields for those entrytypes
\clearfield{url}%
\clearfield{urldate}%
\clearfield{review}%
\clearfield{series}%
}{}%the other entrytypes are nore affected
```

UPDATE: as the other answer tells us, `\ifentrytype` only works with ONE entrytype as its argument.

Comment: Would love to say it works for me, and I fully understand your first comment... but I still get the URL for an incollection entry printed out. I don't get it. It probably needs a real MWE. I'll get back to you on that. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Ok, it doesn't work. Updated my op with real MWE and a picture. :)

Comment: I just came across this answer because of [Biblatex: Surpessing urldate does not work (\clearfield)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278890/35864) and it seems that with the current version `\clearfield{urldate}` doesn't work any more, now `\clearfield{urlyear}` is needed.