# Print school field for @phdthesis

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `numeric-comp` style with biblatex, which doesn't print the school for `@phdthesis`.

```
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  sorting=none,
  giveninits=true,
  useprefix=true,
  backref=true,
  backrefstyle=three,
  style=numeric-comp
]{biblatex}
```

How can I make it print the school name?

Also, I'd like to change the "PhD Thesis" string to "PhD Diss."

Comment: Please post a fully compilable example document including a relevant `.bib` entry. In the standard data model `school` is an alias for `institution`, which is printed. So there must be something irregular going on in your document (in code not shown in the question yet).

Comment: Also please ask only one question per question. While the questions are related, they are clearly distinct, have different answers and can be of separate interest for future visitors. Keeping questions separated makes sure that answers are more relevant and easier to understand. See for example https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864.

Comment: Sorry for not providing a full working example. I hoped that the style was responsible for not getting the `institution` printed and that there was just a simple switch for it. There's a lot going on in my document, and I'll have to progressively cut things out to find what is causing the problem.

Comment: I remembered that I had added `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{institution}}` to remove that field for articles. I solved the problem following the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187763/35990).

Comment: Hrmm, in the standard styles `institution` is never shown for `@article`s, so you shouldn't have to remove it.

Comment: It might have been for reports. I cite a lot of those, too.

Answer (score 2):

The school is printed. The `biblatex` field name is `institution`, though `school` is also supported as an alias. If you're not seeing it, then something else is going wrong and you'll need to provide a proper example that demonstrates your problem.

And you can redefine strings using `\DefineBibliogrpahyStrings`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@thesis{test,
  author       = {Author, An},
  title        = {Thesis Title},
  type         = {phdthesis},
  institution  = {School},
  date         = {1985},
  location     = {Location}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  sorting=none,
  giveninits=true,
  useprefix=true,
  backref=true,
  backrefstyle=three,
  style=numeric-comp
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  phdthesis = {PhD Diss\adddot}
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]