# Biblatex, display URL or DOI field for specific entry types

Tags: biblatex

I use `biblatex` with `biter` and the additional [`biblatex-phys`](https://mirror.foobar.to/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-phys/biblatex-phys.pdf) package to have styles close to the convention of the APS / AIP.

By default the URL option is switched off and regular `article` are displayed with their journal reference being a hypertext link.

For `report` I would like to explicitly display the URL. If I switch on the `URL` option then the URL is shown even for the `article` (which is useless as it already contains a link).

Is there a way to control this behaviour for only a few entry types (`report` and maybe `thesis`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions` you can set the `url` option per entrytype. If you want to enable the option only for `@report` use

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=phys]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[report]{url=true}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@report{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  url       = {https://example.com/bronto.pdf},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,elk}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: A. Elk, A theory on brontosauruses (1972), https://example.com/bronto.pdf.]

Comment: That's just perfect, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

A rather crude way should be to delete the url-information for the entry types where it should not be displayed along the lines of [Biblatex - How can I suppress some fields for multiple entry types?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187643/biblatex-how-can-i-suppress-some-fields-for-multiple-entry-types)

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
\ifentrytype{article}{%
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urldate}%
}{}%
}
```